# Why is this false about limits?

Tags: calculus

If $h(x) = g(x)$ on $(a,b)$, then $\lim_{x \to b^-} h(x) = \lim_{x \to b^-} g(x)$.

What's a good counterexample I can give to show that this is false?

(This is for grading purposes, not homework.)

Comment: Why do you think it's false? (The limits don't have to exist, but they either both exist or both fail to exist.)

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x \to b^{\color{red}{+}}}$? If $h(x)=g(x)$ for all $a < x < b$ then why would the limits differ if they exist?

Comment: The proposition is true when the limit exists. The only way it can fail is when it doesn't.

Comment: got it, thanks so much @MichaelHardy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
h(x) = \sin\left( \frac 1 {b-x} \right) = g(x)
$$

Comment: @D.Hutchinson Say that in your post ;)